# Do I add IDE's files to the git

Tags: git, netbeans, project, setup-project

If I build Netbeans or or any other IDE project with git do I add IDE specific files like:

`manifest.mf nbproject/ lib/ build.xml`

Certainly we do not keep binaries to version system. What files is appropriate to add to git repo? I understand that when building Maven project then only pom.xml is needed, but in case I just click new->project.

Comment: The question I am asking myself in those cases is: Are those files generated files, and can they easily be regenerated from other files? If yes, they usually do not go into the repo. Another criteria is: what is the effort to build the project, once it has been checked out in a fresh, clean environment. Ideally, all you should have to do is to load the IDE's project file, and press the `build&run` button.

Answer (score 1):

You should check in, at a minimum, your `nbproject/configurations.xml` and `nbproject/project.xml` (assuming you have those).  You should also consider checking in the other files in `nbproject/` such as any Makefiles, but do not check in the `private/` subdirectory (again, if you have it).

The reason I check in my Makefiles is that I want to be able to build my project in Jenkins, outside of NetBeans.  Jenkins clones the repo and runs `make` without any IDE support.